# Adding 7 days to all rows with a date from the past 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am charged with the task of solving a scenario based on the following:
The database server had been reset with the wrong date and time without anyone knowing. UPDATE any order date in the past week to add 7 days.

The Orderdate is stored in ORDERS.ORDERDATE. I tried using the following code and it fails:

```
UPDATE ORDERS 
SET  ORDERDATE,DATEADD(day,7,OrderDate)
WHERE DATEDIFF >= (
    DAY, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @ORDERDATE, -7), 
    GETDATE());
```

Can someone provide me with the proper code?

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax appears to be for SQL Server, but you tagged the question for Oracle.  In any case, a correct `UPDATE` query in Oracle should look something like this:

```
UPDATE ORDERS
    SET ORDERDATE = ORDERDATE + INTERVAL '7' DAY
    WHERE ORDERDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

Here `SYSDATE` is a `DATE` object representing the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try with

```
Update ORDERS
   SET ORDERDATE = ORDERDATE + 7
WHERE SYSDATE - ORDERDATE <= 7;
```

Comment: Depending on the volume of data you're going to update, you might need to do a foor loop, and include intermediate commits

Comment: `ORDERDATE = ORDERDATE + 7` works only if datatype of ORDERDATE is `DATE`. For `TIMESTAMP` datatype you have to use `INTERVAL`.